# Problem in Rails scaffold for DATE fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, date, scaffolding, scaffold

When I use Rails scaffold, I can't access the page to edit fields. It shows me some kind of problem with all DATE fields. Here's the error:

```
can't convert Symbol into String

Extracted source (around line #124):

    121:   </p>
    122:   <p>
    123:     <%= f.label :dataDeCadastro %><br />
    124:     <%= f.date_select :dataDeCadastro %>
```

And part of the stackTrace:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:564:in `include?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:564:in `select_date'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:832:in `to_date_select_tag_without_error_wrapping'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb:268:in `to_date_select_tag'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:179:in `date_select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:889:in `date_select'
app/views/usuarios/edit.html.erb:124
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:313:in `fields_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:253:in `form_for'
app/views/usuarios/edit.html.erb:3
```

And the model sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recebeNews` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inscricaoEstadual` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rg` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `complemento` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefoneResidencial` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dddTelefoneCelular` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dddTelefoneComercial` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dddTelefoneResidencial` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ramalDoTelefoneComercial` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefoneCelular` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefoneComercial` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditoPessoal` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descontoPessoal` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `motivoDoBloqueio` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomeNaReceitaFederal` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valorDoCreditoPessoal` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `valorDoDescontoPessoal` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `bloqueio` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataDeCadastro` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataLimiteDoDescontoPessoal` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacaoNaReceitaFederal` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataDeNascimento` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interior` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `observacao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5754 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

full view source:

```
<% form_for(@usuario) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :usuario %>
  <%= f.text_field :usuario %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :cpf, "CPF" %>
  <%= f.text_field :cpf %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :rg, "RG" %>
  <%= f.text_field :rg %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :cnpj, "CNPJ" %>
  <%= f.text_field :cnpj %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :sexo, "Sexo" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :sexo, :M %>M<br>
  <%= f.radio_button :sexo, :F %>F
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :dataDeNascimento, "Data de Nascimento" %>

  <%= f.date_select :dataDeNascimento %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :endereco %>
  <%= f.text_field :endereco %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :cidade, "Cidade" %>
  <%= f.text_field :cidade %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :estado, "Estado" %>
  <%= f.text_field :estado, :maxlength => "2" %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :cep, "CEP" %>
  <%= f.text_field :cep, :maxlength => "10" %> (00000-000)
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :telefone, "Telefone" %>
  <%= f.text_field :telefone %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :senha, "Senha" %>
  <%= f.password_field :senha %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :senha_confirmation, "Confirmação da Senha" %>
  <%= f.password_field :senha_confirmation %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :recebeNews %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :recebeNews %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Enviar" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the solution on [this link](http://i18n.lighthouseapp.com/projects/14947/tickets/12-i18n-and-date_select-exception) and this [one](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/dc94d81):

> When in your application you have set
>   the I18n.locale to something different
>   than "en" and you have the following
>   simple code in your view:

```
 <%= date_select("user_info", "birthdate") %>
```

> You'll get the can't convert Symbol into String for the
>   date_select helper. The problem can be
>   rescued by giving the date_select
>   helper order like this:

```
 <%= date_select("user_info", "birthdate", :order => [:day,:month,:year]) %>
```

> or by doing order in the yml file usually located at config/locales/your_lang.yml like
>   this

```
date:   
  formats: 
    default: ""
    long: ""
    short: ""
  order:
    - :year
    - :month
    - :day
```

Comment: This clearly solves the error, though other problems like month translations missing raise after. I suggest anyone having this issue to copy the whole date tree from https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Answer (score 3):

This is highly likely to be caused by localization. You have entered a different standard locale than :en (in application.rb or environment.rb), but you have not declared the appropriate translations for month names, causing rails to balk. You can download standard translation files from [GitHub](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale).

Answer (score 0):

Could you show also the error-message?

**UPDATE:**

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :dataDeNascimento, "Data de Nascimento" %>

  <%= f.date_select "dataDeNascimento" %>
</p>
```

or try this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :dataDeNascimento, "Data de Nascimento" %>

  <%= date_select "usario", "dataDeNascimento" %>
</p>
```

Comment: please show me your full form-code. Would be good to see your sql-statement as formatted code in your question-text.

Comment: Maybe you should try to pass a string instead of a symbol...

see the code above